# How to let two accounts to work with one device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My wife and I used to share an iPad and we each had a clash of clans account. We used to sign in and out of our Apple id to load our respective villages.

I've recently created another account for my son so when he gets older he can get his own games, apps, etc. But in the meantime I wish to use it for Clash of Clans.

I've created him a Game Center profile and have logged into his Apple id and Game Center but it keeps reloading my village.

Why doesn't it work like it used to with my wife's and mine? How can I make it load a new village?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way Clash of Clans loads villages. If you have an existing village, that village will also bind to any new accounts (that does not have a village yet).

The only safe way for him to get his own village is to:

1. Log of of your existing Game Center account.
2. Uninstall Clash of Clans from your phone and remove any associated data.
   *This is so that your device is no longer binded to a village/account as logging out from Game Center isn't enough as Clash of Clans still loads the last village that it was logged into even when nobody is logged on.*
3. Reinstall Clash of Clans and log into the new Game Center account.
4. Open Clash of Clans and finish the tutorial.

---

Since you've already logged into his new account with your village loaded, your only option is to contact Supercell to remove your village from his account as you cannot delete or unbind villages.